# Can't Connect To SSH over Internet

Tags: networking, router, ssh

I'm trying to setup a small server box (running ubuntu server) and connect to it remotely through ssh, ftp, and a webserver. I've forwarded the necessary ports in my router but I'm not able to connect to them remotely. I am able to connect locally from other machines using the local ip of the machine. Yes, I'm sure that network is connected to the internet. Is my edgerouter blocking incoming connections even though I've forwarded those ports? What can I check?

--edit--
I'm also unable to ping the ip remotely, but do get replies when pinging the ip locally.

[image]

Comment: Post the full text of the actual error message you get when you try to ssh into your machine.  Also, post how you are determining what your public IP is.  Given that you don't get ping results, how are you sure you are pinging the correct IP?

Answer (score 0):

Your ISP may be blocking incoming connections under a "home users do not run servers" clause in your contract.

Comment: Its a business account, so I'm hoping that isnt that case, though may be something to look into to...